# How to install new package version (update package) when there is new update available in repo using shell script

Tags: bash, shell, syntax, command-substitution

I need to write a shell script that upgrade a package by comparing installed and available version. For example git 2.3 is installed in my machine, I need to upgrade to new version (if available) through shell script.

I tried this:

```
#!/bin/bash
package_name=git
INSTALLED_VERSION= rpm -q $package_name
AVAILABLE_VERSION= yum --showduplicates list $package_name
echo $INSTALLED_VERSION
echo $AVAILABLE_VERSION

if [ $INSTALLED_VERSION -lt $AVAILABLE_VERSION ] ; then
        yum install -y  $package_name
fi

# check version:
git --version
```

Comment: Please try https://shellcheck.net/ before asking for human assistance. You have basic syntax errors; the proper syntax for capturing the output of a command is `variable=$(command --with arguments)`

Answer (score 0):

`yum` can do it for you, just run

```
yum update -y "$package_name"
```

and it will update the package if a new version is available.

Comment: So, no need to compare, yum itself automatically compare both the installed and available version?

Comment: Indeed, if there is no update then this simply checks that you have the newest version already.